# Move view along svg bounding box in android scrollview

Tags: android, svg, vector-graphics

I have an svg file in my assets folder, is there a way for me to to access or create a bounding box along its path so that a imageview can only move within the bounds of it?

My use case: I have a scrollview which will contain these svg paths, each linked at ends, ie. where one ends another begins up to the top of the scrollview. I want to center my imageview within the svg's path so that the imageview's Y position is centered and follows the user scroll but its x position follows the svg path and stays within the limits of the svg's path's stroke width as it changes through the scroll, up to the limit of the svg path.

I know there have been some libraries that parse paths, but the svg's that I'm working with are all relative to each other within a bound larger than the screen, essentially the size of the scrollview which is why I've had a hard time putting the components together.

I'm pretty new in working with coordinates to any help would appreciated.

I'm attaching a pic to hopefully make the question clearer.

[image]

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what you are trying to do.  Perhaps you can post an illustration?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I've updated the question, I have an svg file, essentially a path. I need to move an image along that path as I scroll up and down. I hope that helps.